# Is there an option to find array inside array?

Tags: python-3.x, image, numpy, matplotlib

i need to build a function that can set in which part the big circle belong to (top , bottom, undermined),
the minimum size of the circle is 3x3.
black color = 1
white color = 0

for example:
 https://serving.photos.photobox.com/17525810496b857f6fc6a1bd5b21ad9fba80f1e6c878dc45d05764a04f861e026fb52115.jpg "example images"

i thought to split my image to half 
(image[0:len(image)/2] and image[len(image)/2:]) ( the numbers of row is even) 
and find a way to looking for array inside array, ( a minimum of 3x3) to find solution to this problem, but i dunno how to realize it.

Comment: The title of your question (find an array inside array) is properly not understandable. What you want to do is to find regions with similar properties within an image. Try to google convolution or blob detection as a starting point.

Comment: you may cross-correlate your image with the "ideal" image you want to locate, then look for the maximum of correlation to get the position of the black circle. Alternatively, a simple horizontal and vertical stack of your array should give you a good idea of the position of the circle since its black on most the image is white...